# How to calculate tautological classes of some varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I want to calculate tautological classes of some subvarieties sitting inside some bigger variety in the cohomology ring of that bigger variety. For example, suppose we have a chain of closed subvarieties $X_{1}\subseteq X_{2}\subseteq \cdots \subseteq \Bbb{P}^{n}$  inside the projective space of dimension $n$. I want to calculate tautological class of $[X_i]$ 's inside cohomology ring of $\Bbb{P}^{n}$,i.e, inside $H^\ast(\Bbb{P}^{n},\Bbb{Z})$. I would like to have some suggestions or some references related to the question.

Comment: I guess you mean the fundamental class. If $\dim X_i= d$, $[X_i]$ equals $\deg X_i$ times the generator of $H^{2d}(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DonuArapura Sir for your answer. I hope by deg $X_i$ you mean it in terms of intersection theory , which is dependent upon how $X_i$ sits inside $\Bbb{P}^n$. If I don't know the map through which $X_i$ is sitting inside  $\Bbb{P}^n$ precisely, then can it be calculated independently  via cohomology,  i.e, if possible not using chow ring??

Comment: If $L$ is linear space of complementary dimension in general position, $\deg X_i$ is the cardinality of $X_i\cap L$. Equivalently, it is the intersection number $X_i\cdot L$.  So you'll need some information about the embedding, but not very much.